# Explain Dask-cuDF behavior

Tags: python, dask, chunking, rapids, cudf

I try to read and process the 8gb csv file using `cudf`. Reading all file at once doesn't fit neither into GPU memory nor into my RAM. That's why I use the `dask_cudf` library. Here is the code:

```
import dask_cudf as dcf
import dask.dataframe as dd

exceptions = ["a", "b", "t", "c"]
x = dcf.read_csv("./data/all.csv", blocksize="256 MiB", sep=',', header=0, decimal='.', skip_blank_lines=True)
x["timestamp"] = dd.to_datetime(x["t"])
x = x.set_index("timestamp", sorted=False)
x = x.loc[pd.to_datetime("2020-01-01 00:00:00"):]
x = x.drop(columns=exceptions)
x.to_csv("./data/")
```

And it works and does produce a bunch of csv files like `00.part`, `01.part` and so on. While processing the data I can see in the task manager that the GPU memory is being used. But in the project root directory I can see the `cufile.log`.
Which says this:

> 25-01-2024 12:18:54:703 [pid=11847 tid=11862] ERROR  0:140 unable to
> load,  liburcu-bp.so.6
>
> 25-01-2024 12:18:54:703 [pid=11847 tid=11862] ERROR  0:140 unable to
> load,  liburcu-bp.so.1
>
> 25-01-2024 12:18:54:704 [pid=11847 tid=11862] WARN   0:168 failed to
> open /proc/driver/nvidia-fs/devcount  error: No such file or directory
>
> 25-01-2024 12:18:54:704 [pid=11847 tid=11862] NOTICE  cufio-drv:727
> running in compatible mode
>
> 25-01-2024 12:18:54:704 [pid=11847 tid=11862] ERROR  cufio-plat:98
> cannot open path /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/resource No such
> file or directory
>
> 25-01-2024 12:18:54:705 [pid=11847 tid=11862] WARN   cufio-plat:431
> GPU index 0 NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060: Model Not Supported
>
> 25-01-2024 12:18:54:705 [pid=11847 tid=11862] WARN   cufio-udev:168
> failed in udev device create: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0
>
> 25-01-2024 12:18:54:899 [pid=11847 tid=11862] ERROR
> cufio-topo-udev:431 no device entries present in platform topology

I have

```
Windows 10 22H2 (19045.3930)
WSL 2.0.9.0 with Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Cuda compilation tools, release 12.0, V12.0.76 Build cuda_12.0.r12.0/compiler.31968024_0 (from windows console)
NVIDIA-SMI 546.65 (from wsl distro terminal)
Driver Version: 546.65 (from wsl distro terminal)
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 6144MiB
cudf 23.12.01
dask-cudf 23.12.01
```

While doing all the job the CPU is also extensively loaded. So does it actually use my GPU or used the CPU as a fallback strategy? Processing this code took 16 minutes. The file says that it was running in some kind of compatability mode and my GPU is not supported. The [docs](https://docs.rapids.ai/install#system-req) state that:

> NVIDIA Pascal™ or better with compute capability 6.0+

which is the case for 1060.

Comment: which docs contain the statement "NVIDIA Pascal™ or better with compute capability 6.0+" and in what context?

Comment: RAPIDS installation guide has system requirements. Updated the post with the link.

Comment: "I can see in the task manager that the GPU memory is being used" - sounds like the answer to me :)

Comment: No driver, no device, not supported platform, but it worked with gpu? What are all these errors about then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your GPU is being utilized by dask-cudf, based on the GPU memory usage you mentioned.

The log messages you're seeing are specific to a feature for GPU Direct Storage (GDS). If GDS is supported, the system can accelerate I/O operations and avoid some CPU-GPU copying in favor of direct memory access from the storage to the GPU. However, GDS is only supported on "Data Center and Quadro (desktop) cards with compute capability >6" (https://docs.nvidia.com/gpudirect-storage/release-notes/index.html#support-matrix). Your GPU is a GeForce GTX 1060, which is not supported for GDS because it is not a Data Center or Quadro card (it has compute capability 6.1, according to this chart: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus#compute). You'll still get GPU speedup for the computations, but not direct memory transfers from storage to GPU memory.

The lack of GDS support should not be too much of a problem for performance, but the small memory size (6 GB) of your GTX 1060 card may be a significant limitation for the data sizes you can process. dask-cudf is a good way to chunk the problem into small enough sizes to fit in your GPU memory, but keep that in mind as you decide on the file/chunk sizes to process if you experience out-of-memory errors.